# How to export socketIO instance into separate file?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am attempting to use an existing socket.io connection to emit an event in another file; however, regardless of what I try, nothing seems to be working. I'm now trying to separate the instance into another file so that any file can import and use it, but the primary issue I get is that either the IO does not connect, or the emit function doesn't do anything (it stalls the function, but no errors).

My question is how I can get the socketIO code out of index.js and put it in a separate file.
I have tried many of the answers on similar threads and none of them seem to work.

This is the file that is using the external instance:

`actions.js`

```js
const cron = require('node-cron')
const io = require('../index').io
module.exports.startActions = async (sessionID, userID, actionType, area = '', resume=false) => {
   /* setup code, no socket.io usage */
  const task = cron.schedule('*/6 * * * * *', async () => {
        /*
        all tasks run smoothly
        */
        // although it says io.emit, I initially was using the socket object with the same result
        // regardless if io is defined (when printed it shows an object) or not ({}) , this doesn't execute
        io.to(sessionID).emit('action-tick', {
            message: 'action tick',
            actionType: actionType,
            time: Date.now(),
            interval: 6, // seconds
            actionsLeft: actionsRemaining
        })
        console.log('emitted') // never prints
    }, {
        name: sessionID
    })
  }
}
```

This is my index.js file - currently everything here works

`index.js`

```js
const express = require('express'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express(); 
const PORT = 3000; 

const cors = require('cors')
const fs = require('fs')

const http = require('http')

const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const server = http.createServer(app)


const session = require('express-session')

const sessionConfig = session({
    secret: '[secret key]',
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: false,
        secure:  false, 
        sameSite: 'lax',
        maxAge: 1000*60*60*24,
    },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: mongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: process.env.DB_CONNECT_URI,
    })
})

app.use(sessionConfig)


app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    credentials: true,
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());


server.listen(PORT, (error) =>{ 
    if(!error) 
        console.log("Server is Successfully Running, and App is listening on port " + PORT) 
    else 
        console.log("Error occurred, server can't start", error); 
    } 
);

const io = socketIO(server)
io.engine.use(sessionConfig)

io.use((socket, next) => {
const checkSession = (socket) => {
        if (!socket.request.session) {
        console.log('no session, logging out')
        io.to(socket.id).emit('logout')
    } else {
        console.log('credentials good')
    }
}
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
// many socket.on statements - these all work correctly
})

module.exports.io = io  //when imported, this is usually {} and not useful
module.exports.server = server
```

How do I get the socket.io parts of the code into a separate folder (such as `socket.js`)?

My attempt at doing this was as so:

`socket.js`

```js
const server = require('./index').server

const io = new Server(server, {
// I have tried pretty much every possible CORS combination that makes sense
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:5173", 
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        credentials: true,
    }

})

module.exports = io
```

but this is giving me quite a few issues; I'm sure there are some faults with this.
No matter what I seem to return or export, the io instance doesn't do anything in `actions.js`.

On a side note, having to import server from ./index is also giving a circular dependency warning but I'm not sure if that's super important.

Comment: Try named export like 
`module.exports = { io };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To separate socket.js file from the index.js file, you can follow the following example.

1. Create `socketHandler.js` file with the following code in it

```js
const socketIO = require('socket.io')

let io;

const initSocket = (server) => {
    io = socketIO(server);

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log("Socket connected")
    })

    // Handle socket event using socket.on()
}

const getIO = () => {
    if (!io) {
        throw new Error('Socket.IO not initialized!');
      }
      return io;
}

module.exports = {
    initSocket,
    getIO
}
```

2. Create `app.js` file, which will have express server and it will invoke socketHanlder `initSocket` to create socket server

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const { initSocket } = require('./socketHandler');
const path = require('path');


const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);

initSocket(server);   // Initialize socket server

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // Send the index.html file as the response
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
  });


server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 5000');
});
```

3. `index.html` in public folder

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Socket.IO Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Socket.IO Example</h1>
  
  <!-- Include Socket.IO library -->
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.3.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    // Connect to the server
    const socket = io();
   
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, run app.js using `node app.js`. Now, when you will hit http://localhost:5000. You will successfully be able to make socket connection with your app however your socket code is in separate file.

Comment: Will this let me use the socket instance in other files as well?

Comment: I am not sure about this, But I have created one separate socket service and might be done that. I will look back into that and update you by today (Asia/Kolkata). I also have one alternative if you want to try.

Comment: 1. For emitting socket events, you can implement a socket_emit() function within the same file. This function only requires the event_name, room, and payload parameters, and import anywhere you need.
2. To manage incoming events, organize separate functions within your project and place them conveniently. In your socket.js file, set up event listeners and import the respective methods to handle further processing.

Comment: Solved it with this, thank you!